# Numbering is stuck to the title in the table of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, titles

i have a problem in my table of figures, numbering is stuck to the title.. when the number is short every thing is fine but once the number become bigger it makes a problem. Any solution please ?[image]

Here is the code i use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. It is probably that the numbering `III.20` is longer than the designer of the template would have expected. Tell us the template you are using; and include in your question a piece of latex code that can compile and illustrate the your problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using a template so its my own code. I added my code in the question. thank you!

Comment: It would REALLY simplify matter to NOT include the chapter number in \thesection and \thefigure.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `tocloft` package and increase the space for figure numbers.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2em} % or more (or less)
```

See the manual via `texdoc tocloft`.

Comment: It doesn't work, it's showing me an error : "You can't use `the letter c' after \advance."

Comment: @OussamaAmine It was my fault. I said `cftfignumwidth` instead of `\cftfignumwidth`. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use tocloft...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{3.5em}{}{chapter Failed!}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{5.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{6.1em}}
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{7em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{8em}}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.3em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% number subparagraphs
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}% show subparagraph

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Short number}
\setcounter{chapter}{17}%
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}
\subsection{My subsection}
\subsubsection{My subsubsection}
\paragraph{My paragraph}
\subparagraph{My subparagraph}

\begin{figure}
\caption{My figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```